# How to call a method of a React component inside mounted Provider in test

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I write an unit test with enzyme and try to call a method of a component.

```
let wrapper = mount(<Provider>
                        <MyComponent />
                      </Provider>);
```

How do I invoke a method of MyComponent?

Answer (score 0):

I would make a shallow wrapper for that.

```
const shallowWrapper = <MyComponent />

shallowWrapper.instance().myMethod()
```

Comment: I was trying to test a bigger scope but I guess I will do the shallow smaller scope testing.

Comment: I will leave this question open in case there is method to do so and someone would contribute from the knowledge for others. Have your upvote anyway :)